# partialinfo.plist couldn't be found error in Xcode 6.3.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I am working on a project in which the error comes as

> error: could not read data from
>   '/Users/administrator/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SplashViewController-PartialInfo.plist':
>   The file “SplashViewController-PartialInfo.plist” couldn’t be opened
>   because there is no such file.

I have tried cleaning, deleting derived data from window ->projects, and again cleaning. Sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't.

One of my project member is using Xcode 7. Will that be a problem behind this.....

Pleaaaaase help me. ... I am working on an update for old project ....

Comment: how come there is a spell mistake on the path u provided ? I assume you copy-pasted the path. Isn't it supposed to be derived instead of dnerived ?

Comment: can u see the plsit in your project file ? If yes, find it in finder and add it back to the respective path

Comment: @Mr.T There is no such file !  I have checked in finder and in project.